# Installing app from Market when it was previously installed

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation

I'm developing an app that was just released. Prior to release, I had 10 or so testers that helped me test the app and had test versions on their phones. Now I want them to install the app from the Market so they can be some of the first people to (fairly) rate the app.

The problem is, even after uninstalling the test version of the app, when trying to get it from the market an error pops up saying that "there was an error creating your order." They can't install it. Is there something I or they can do about this?

**Update:** I told the testers to follow the instructions under **[Troubleshooting Download Issues](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1067233) -> "Download unsuccessful" message**. This did not work.

Comment: Are others experiencing this issue as well? I'm trying to figure out what the up votes mean.. and if it's just me or not.

Comment: Upvote most of the time just mean's a well formed question.

Answer (score 1):

You could *cheat* and change the package name for the uploaded app to the market. That way you won't have to instruct your beta users' to do anything differently.

In the future whilst in beta:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.your.app.beta"
```

Then once you want to release just do a little refactor:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.your.app"
```